# Docusign - History (via a third party app)

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to use the API to show the history of a Docusign envelope?

For example if a user creates an envelope using the Docusign website, could we show the history of the envelope (when it was created, if the person was chased etc..) in one of our software, the history of the envelope would need to show against the correct case in our software.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can show the history of the envelope, but first you need to get consent from the user whose envelopes you are trying to pull. You need to get Consent from that user by following steps as explained in [API Auth](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication). Once you get consent then you will generate Access Token for that user with proper scope, and with access token you can pull the audit history etc of that envelope to show it in your App. Example of audit event API call is [Audit API](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/listAuditEvents)